# Injecting c++ dll into an exe using c#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

Why my C# code didn't inject dll into an exe but the program show me the message box "Injected!" ?
The .dll it self is coded with c++ , and the exe is coded with C++
and i'm trying to inject with my C# code, How it not working ?
This is my injector method

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public static extern IntPtr CreateRemoteThread(
  IntPtr hProcess,
  IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
  uint dwStackSize,
  UIntPtr lpStartAddress, // raw Pointer into remote process
  IntPtr lpParameter,
  uint dwCreationFlags,
  out IntPtr lpThreadId
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(
    UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
    Int32 bInheritHandle,
    Int32 dwProcessId
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 CloseHandle(
IntPtr hObject
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern bool VirtualFreeEx(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpAddress,
    UIntPtr dwSize,
    uint dwFreeType
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern UIntPtr GetProcAddress(
    IntPtr hModule,
    string procName
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
static extern IntPtr VirtualAllocEx(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpAddress,
    uint dwSize,
    uint flAllocationType,
    uint flProtect
    );

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool WriteProcessMemory(
    IntPtr hProcess,
    IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
    string lpBuffer,
    UIntPtr nSize,
    out IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesWritten
);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(
    string lpModuleName
    );

[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
internal static extern Int32 WaitForSingleObject(
    IntPtr handle,
    Int32 milliseconds
    );

public Int32 GetProcessId(String proc)
{
    Process[] ProcList;
    ProcList = Process.GetProcessesByName(proc);
    return ProcList[0].Id;
}

public void InjectDLL(IntPtr hProcess, String strDLLName)
{
    IntPtr bytesout;

    // Length of string containing the DLL file name +1 byte padding
    Int32 LenWrite = strDLLName.Length + 1;
    // Allocate memory within the virtual address space of the target process
    IntPtr AllocMem = (IntPtr)VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, (uint)LenWrite, 0x1000, 0x40); //allocation pour WriteProcessMemory

    // Write DLL file name to allocated memory in target process
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, AllocMem, strDLLName, (UIntPtr)LenWrite, out bytesout);
    // Function pointer "Injector"
    UIntPtr Injector = (UIntPtr)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");

    if (Injector == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(" Injector Error! \n ");
        // return failed
        return;
    }

    // Create thread in target process, and store handle in hThread
    IntPtr hThread = (IntPtr)CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, (IntPtr)null, 0, Injector, AllocMem, 0, out bytesout);
    // Make sure thread handle is valid
    if (hThread == null)
    {
        //incorrect thread handle ... return failed
        MessageBox.Show(" hThread [ 1 ] Error! \n ");
        return;
    }
    // Time-out is 10 seconds...
    int Result = WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 10 * 1000);
    // Check whether thread timed out...
    if (Result == 0x00000080L || Result == 0x00000102L || Result == 0xFFFFFFFF)
    {
        /* Thread timed out... */
        MessageBox.Show(" hThread [ 2 ] Error! \n ");
        // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
        if (hThread != null)
        {
            //Close thread in target process
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        return;
    }
    // Sleep thread for 1 second
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // Clear up allocated space ( Allocmem )
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, AllocMem, (UIntPtr)0, 0x8000);
    // Make sure thread handle is valid before closing... prevents crashes.
    if (hThread != null)
    {
        //Close thread in target process
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
    // return succeeded
    return;
}
```

And then i try to running some program and inject it with my dll

```
private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strDLLName = @"spd.dll";
    String strProcessName = "app";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("app.exe", "!#@$$$!");                                   
    Int32 ProcID = GetProcessId(strProcessName);
    if (ProcID >= 0)
    {
        IntPtr hProcess = (IntPtr)OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, 1, ProcID);
        if (hProcess == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("OpenProcess() Failed!");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            InjectDLL(hProcess, strDLLName);
            MessageBox.Show("Injected!");  
        }

    }

}
```

It show me the output : "Injected!" but on .exe the .dll is not injected
What should i do ? Giving more Thread.Sleep before Inject / After running the .exe ?
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hey Bayu Anggara, this is really useful code, man! Would you mind sending me the working version to fischermartin91@gmail.com? I've been looking for this recently.

Comment: @bytecode77 Hey byte! Glad to hear that! the code above is the working version , and for the update , i just answer this question, you can look at my answer below :)

Comment: Thanks. I also got it working by now. I'm gonna try building a rootkit. Let's see how far I can take this idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is shamefully , many of my stackoverflow question answered by myself,
the idea is always come late (after i post the question)
so this is the answer
The injector above is working correctly , and why the injector didn't inject it ?
yes this is like my thought before , the injector not injected dll successfully because of i need to give Thread.Sleep(1000) after start the app and before injecting the .dll , and using Worker, Like this :

```
void worker_DoWork2(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("app.exe", "!#@$$$!");

        }

public void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var worker2 = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker2.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork2);
            worker2.RunWorkerAsync();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            String strDLLName = "spd.dll";
            String strProcessName = "app";    
            Int32 ProcID = GetProcessId(strProcessName);
            if (ProcID >= 0)
            {
                IntPtr hProcess = (IntPtr)OpenProcess(0x1F0FFF, 1, ProcID);
                if (hProcess == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    InjectDLL(hProcess, strDLLName);
                }  
            }
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Now the injector work successfully , and i need to run this application with administrator privilege.
Thank you !

Comment: Hey dude, I know it is too late or whatever, but I need your help. I made a windows form application in C# and used AutoFrost and GrayFrost projects to create DLL which bootstraps .NET runtime and starts C# application when injected. 
When I manually import the generated Loader.DLL in (let's say for example) C++ dummy project, it works fine. However, when I inject the DLL into running process, it has no effect :( 
Do you have a working example right now?

Comment: @user218046 hi sorry, I don't think so, because currently my app didn't inject dll when running, however I think if you want to inject DLL into running process, you need to learn dll hook. you can google Hook dll into running process . Hope it help :)

Answer (score 3):

Take note that `C++`'s`NULL`(0) is not the same as `C#`'s `null`. The equivalent you are looking for is `IntPtr.Zero`.

---

Take `GetProcAddress` function for example :

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the address of the exported function or variable.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.
>
> Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212(v=vs.85).aspx

This `NULL` here is a c++ macro which is defined as :

```
#define NULL 0
```

---

`null` is not equal to `IntPtr.Zero`, but `(IntPtr)null` is equal to `IntPtr.Zero`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the comment , so i need to change (IntPtr)null into InPtr.Zero ?

Comment: Okay i got it , (IntPtr)null is different with IntPtr.Zero , so i need to change (IntPtr)null to InPtr.Zero on my injector method? please more detail :)

Comment: Sorry, my previous comment was wrong. See my updated answer for correction.